# How can I multiplex output to an OS file descriptor in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

The `subprocess.Popen` mechanism uses an underlying file descriptor, instead of a file-like object, to write its `stdout/stderr`. I need to capture both the `stdout` and `stderr` while still displaying them to the console.

How can I create a file descriptor that Popen can use that will allow me to do this?

Comment: what about capturing using subprocess.Popen and then printing them back to all fd you need

Comment: No can do; I can't buffer the actual output to the stderr/stdout streams; the user might be interacting with the process.

Comment: I [answered to another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984549/merge-and-sync-stdout-and-stderr/5188359#5188359) which you may be able to modify to read the stdout/stderr together incrementally while also printing them to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Just a bit of context: `subprocess` [uses the raw file descriptors](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L1306) of the *stdin*, *stdout*, *stderr* objects you specify, because [it passes them down to POSIX](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c#L391). If you use `subprocess.PIPE`, then it will create a new pipe with `os.pipe()`. Also, `Popen.communicate` reads until the end of the stream, which may not be desirable if you want to pipe the data somewhere else.

Since you want to print the output to *stdout*, I assume it's text output. You will need to use `encoding`, `errors` or `universal_newlines` in `Popen` for `subprocess` to treat the file as text (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout)).

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    '/usr/bin/whoami',
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  # Control stdout
    universal_newlines=True  # Files opened in text mode
)

# Pipe the data somewhere else too, e.g.: a log file
with open('subprocess.log', 'w') as logfile:
    # p.poll() returns the return code when `p` exits
    while p.poll() is None:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        # one to our stdout (readline includes the \n)
        print(line, end='')
        # one to the logfile
        logfile.write(line)
```

The same technique can be used for manipulating *stderr*, for example, by passing `file=sys.stderr` to `print`. Note that you can also pipe from your own *stdin* just by passing it directly:

```
subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/whoami', stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, ...)
```

After all, the standard streams just wrap file descriptors. If reading until the end of the line is unsuitable for the type of output you are expecting, you can just `read` a very short buffer.

### Working simultaneously with *stderr* and *stdout*

If you need both *stdout* and *stderr*, you come to the problem that you can only read from one at a time.
One possibility would be to use `os.set_blocking` to make the pipes non-blocking, so that any `read` method returns immediately if there is no data. This allows you to alternate between the streams.
Another possibility, is to have two separate threads process *stdout* and *stderr*; but there is a simpler way to achieve this by means of the [`aysncio` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-using-transport-and-protocol):

```
import asyncio
import sys

PROCESS_PATH = '/bin/mixed_output'

class MultiplexProtocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol):
    def __init__(self, exit_future):
        self.exit_future = exit_future

    def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
        if fd == sys.stdout.fileno():
            print(data.decode('utf-8'), file=sys.stdout, end='')
        elif fd == sys.stderr.fileno():
            print(data.decode('utf-8'), file=sys.stderr, end='')

    def process_exited(self):
        self.exit_future.set_result(True)


async def launch_subprocess(loop):
    # Future marking the end of the process
    exit_future = asyncio.Future(loop=loop)
    # Use asyncio's subprocess
    create_subp = loop.subprocess_exec(
        lambda: MultiplexProtocol(exit_future),
        PROCESS_PATH,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=None
    )
    transport, protocol = await create_subp
    await exit_future
    # Close the pipes
    transport.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(launch_subprocess(loop))
```

This is much less CPU consuming than constantly looping in the host process to pipe data to other streams, as `MultiplexProtocol.pipe_data_received` is called only when needed.