# Use Python Popen to benchmark a script?

Tags: python, process, benchmarking, popen

I have a script (it's a hadoop pig script to b precice) from which I want to measure the execution time. I might planned to run the tests several times and take the average / median time as the execution time.

As starting the script several times by hand might get quite cumbersome, I wanted to write a script for running these tests.

Is it a good idea to use Python's Popen to start a new process that executes the script and measure the time that process is running, say:

```
# start timer
p = subprocess.Popen(...)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
# end timer
```

Does creating a new process skew the results in time measurements, or is this apporoach fine? Any other suggestions?

Best,
Will

Comment: Instead of the while-loop, simply use `p.communicate()` to wait for the process to finish.  (Or `p.wait()` if you do not redirect the output.)

Comment: thanks, and what if my script produces a lot of output? does p.communicate buffer the whole output until it prints it? is there a way to print partial output / flush the buffer regularly?

Comment: Alternatively, on Linux you can use the time command to benchmark how much a process has been running. For example, "time myprog" will run myprog and tell you at the end how much time it took.

Comment: check [my answer here for how to incrementally read stdout/stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984549/merge-and-sync-stdout-and-stderr/5188359#5188359), might be useful if you need to do this in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also just use the `time` utility:

```
time python foo.py
```

You can then make a bash script to run this multiple times, recording the time taken for each run. Then, just average them with a shell utility or a Python script.