# subprocess.communicate() sending garbage to process?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm having problems reading/writing to stdin/stdout in a child process with subprocess.communicate().

This is the child process (in C)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char buf[128];
    printf("test\n");
    gets(buf);
    printf("%s", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the program in python that calls that child program

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('./test', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

stdin, stderr = proc.communicate()
print stdin
proc.communicate(stdin)
stdin, stderr = proc.communicate()
print stdin

print stdin
```

I would expect this to print

```
test
input was test:
```

However, it seems that proc.communicate() causes an EOF for gets(), causing the child application to terminate. Is there anyway I can communicate with the child application without sending an EOF? IE I would like to read to the application AND THEN write to it.

Comment: I accepted the answer below because it was very important to finding the solution to my problem. I also wanted to add that I needed a `fflush(stdout);` as input was being buffered and this was causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`Popen.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

This means that you can only call `communicate()` once for your subprocess.

Getting real time output can be kind of tricky, but in your example it shouldn't be too difficult since you are only attempting to read a single line.  The following should work:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('./test', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

outdata = proc.stdout.readline()
print outdata
outdata, errdata = proc.communicate('output was ' + outdata)
print outdata
```

Note that I renamed some of your variables, since the output from your subprocess is not really stdin for your Python process.

Comment: +1.  You might also decided not to use communicate() at all.  For an example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322796/keep-a-subprocess-alive-and-keep-giving-it-commands-python/9327923#9327923

Comment: Is it possible to wait on command which we pass to communicate? Example: i have cmd1, cmd2, cmd3 as commands passed to communicate. Can i wait for 5s after each command execution?