# keep a subprocess alive and keep giving it commands python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

The code from the accepted answer to [Keep a subprocess alive and keep giving it commands? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322796/keep-a-subprocess-alive-and-keep-giving-it-commands-python) isn't working in python 3.6 (it just hangs). Is there a way to fix it?

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Run "cat", which is a simple Linux program that prints it's input.
process = Popen(['/bin/cat'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf-8', universal_newlines=True)
process.stdin.write('Hello\n')
print(repr(process.stdout.readline())) # Should print 'Hello\n'
process.stdin.write(b'World\n')
print(repr(process.stdout.readline())) # Should print 'World\n'

# "cat" will exit when you close stdin.  (Not all programs do this!)
process.stdin.close()
print('Waiting for cat to exit')
process.wait()
print('cat finished with return code %d' % process.returncode)
```

Comment: Where is it hanging? What OS are you running on? Can you confirm that `cat` is actually executing?

Comment: Also: if this code works on Python 2.x and fails on 3.x, I'd assume it's a bytes-vs-unicode thing. Try specifying `encoding='utf-8'` in the `Popen` constructor.

Comment: Oh, and if you're on a non-Unix OS, you'll definitely need `universal_newlines=True` in the `Popen` constructor as well.

Comment: mac os 10.12 Anaconda python 2.7 hangs on readline. unfortunately adding encoding doesn't help

Comment: nor does universal_newlines

Comment: just tested on Ubuntu 17.10 and reproduced the error

Comment: I would next try `strace` to watch what's actually going on between the processes. It might be a stdio buffer: does explicitly flushing the process's stdin help?

Comment: aha `flush` solves it!

Comment: It's hanging on line 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between `cat` and your program is a buffer, most likely in the libc stdio implementation on the Python side. You need to flush this buffer to ensure `cat` has seen the bytes you wrote before putting your process to sleep waiting for `cat` to write some bytes back.

You can do this explicitly with a `process.stdin.flush()` call, or you can do it implicitly by disabling the buffer. I think the explicit form is probably better here: it's simple and clearly correct.

Answer (score 4):

As per @DanielPryden's suggestion, you need to explicitly flush the stdin:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Run "cat", which is a simple Linux program that prints it's input.
process = Popen(['/bin/cat'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
process.stdin.write(b'Hello\n')
process.stdin.flush()
print(repr(process.stdout.readline())) # Should print 'Hello\n'
process.stdin.write(b'World\n')
process.stdin.flush()
print(repr(process.stdout.readline())) # Should print 'World\n'

# "cat" will exit when you close stdin.  (Not all programs do this!)
process.stdin.close()
print('Waiting for cat to exit')
process.wait()
print('cat finished with return code %d' % process.returncode)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.6 (and in other versions as far as I know), process.stdin.write takes a byte object, not a string.

```
process.stdin.write(b'Hello\n')
```

EDIT: This answer was invalidated after the edit to the question. (It added an encoding to the Popen constructor.)

Comment: Actually, this is printing `5` for me, so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Really? I get `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` on `process.stdin.write('test\n')`. This is in IDLE 3.6.2

Comment: are you sure your're running python 3?

Comment: It takes a Unicode string if you set an encoding, or a bytestring otherwise.

Comment: @maxymoo Yes. I started IDLE with `idle3`.

Comment: @DanielPryden How do you set an encoding?

Comment: @OldBunny2800: with the `encoding` parameter of the `Popen` constructor. Use `help(subprocess.Popen)` for more information.