# Python subprocess: Passing multiple inputs/outputs back and forth

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use subproccess.Popen to allow two Python programs to more or less have a conversation. I want to be able to send input from the parent to the child, receive the child's response, and then based on that response, send a new input. subprocess.communicate() closes the process after one I/O interaction. Is it possible to leave the same subprocess open for multiple I/Os? Currently, my code hangs.

Parent code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
import sys


try:
     p = subprocess.Popen(['python','childprocess.py'],
                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                          bufsize=1,
                          universal_newlines=True)
except Exception as e:
     print("Error: "+str(e))
     sys.exit(-1)

p.stdin.write('This is the first input\n')
p.stdin.flush()
print(p.stdout.readline())
p.stdin.write('This is the second input\n')
print(p.stdout.readline())
```

Child code:

```
input_one = raw_input()
print "Input One: ",input_one
input_two = raw_input()
print "Input Two: ",input_two
```

In this case, I can just give the two inputs and then read the two outputs, but if I wanted to be able to use the child output to inform the parent input (e.g. a number guesser), can I do that with subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the subprocess.Popen() function, which keeps the process alive.

Related S.O. question for reference:

[Keep a subprocess alive and keep giving it commands? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322796/keep-a-subprocess-alive-and-keep-giving-it-commands-python)

Comment: I'm using Popen(), and when I only have a single input, or multiple inputs before the outputs, it works fine. But when try to have a back-and-forth between the processes using the code above, they hang indefinitely.

Comment: Popen is supposed to be used for the [Child Process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), not the parent.