# Keep open new terminal using subprocess in Linux

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess

I am trying to open a new terminal through a python script and run a linux command in it using subprocess().

This is the code I used:

```
import subprocess

command="subprocess.run('ls')"

subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'bash', '-c', command], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It launches a terminal but then closes immediately after, and I cannot find if the command got executed at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9327923/19835828

Comment: @no_modules No, it launches the subprocess inside the same terminal.

Comment: If you activate an input prompt for the user between each command, does it stay open?

Comment: Should `command="subprocess.run('ls')"` just be `command="ls"`? In this example you could try something like  `command="ls;read"`. So it runs the first command then waits for user input which should keep it open.