# How to call `subprocess` efficiently (and avoid calling it in a loop)

Tags: python, for-loop, subprocess

I have a Python script that contains a for-loop that iterates through a list of items. I need to perform a computation on a property of each item, but the code that does this computation is in Java (where the java `main()` method accepts two arguments: `arg1` and `arg2` in the example below). So far, so good -- I can use `subprocess` to call Java.

This is how I do it currently (simplified):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cp = ... # my classpath string
java_file = ... # the file with the java code
arg1 = ... # an argument string (always the same value) 
items = [...] # my list of items
for item in items:
    args2 = ... # calculated from item inside the python script 
    cmd = ['java', '-cp', cp, java_file, arg1, arg2]
    process = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    output, errors = process.communicate()
    outp_str = output.decode('utf-8') # the result I need
```

It works, but because my list can contain thousands of elements, I'd be calling `subprocess` as many times -- which seems very inefficient.

Is there a way in which I can call `subprocess` only once, before the loop, and then give the active subprocess the necessary command within the loop? Or would that make no sense in terms of speed/efficiency?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322796/keep-a-subprocess-alive-and-keep-giving-it-commands-python) question, which seems to be related -- but I can't manage to translate this to my scenario. I also did not find my solution in the [docs for subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). I imagine it would be something like this:

```
cp = ... # my classpath string
java_file = ... # the file with the java code
arg1 = ... # an argument string (always the same value)
cmd = [...] # <-- ???
process = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True) 
items = [...] # my list of items
for item in items:
    args2 = ... # calculated from item inside the python script
    process.stdin.write(bytes(..., 'utf-8')) # <-- ???
    process.stdin.flush()
    result = process.stdout.readline() # the result I need
```

... where I can't figure out what the two commands should be (in the lines that have the question marks).

Is what I want possible? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: In order to work with `stdin`, the Java application has to be implemented to read from its standard input and perform the desired actions when input is received. So, if your Java application does not implement that functionality, or provide any other way to communicate further work to it after it's started, and it can only accept two arguments when launched, then you have no choice but to launch a new process for every two arguments.

Comment: btw, you should be using `subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, shell=False)` no point in starting an unnecessary shell

Comment: "I can't figure out what the two commands should be (in the lines that have the question marks)." how are we supposed to know how some unsepcified program works? Does it even accept input from stdin?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry for unclear wording. The command should be `['java', '-cp', cp, java_file, arg1, arg2]`, as in the upper example -- but I was wondering whether I can split this up into one half that has the fixed arguments, and one that has the variable argument.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not sure if I understand you correctly -- the Java program accepts anything I want it to accept. I just pass String arguments to its `main()` and change the Java code accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying, your code does that, no? All I was saying is that you should use `subprocess.run` instead of the `Popen` constructor directly, since you just want to invoke the command and wait for it to finish and retreive the output, which is what `subprocess.run` is for. But also, you don't want `shell=True`, that is unnecessary and in your case adds additional inefficiency

Comment: I am certain that it *does not* just accept anything. Do you understand what `process.stdin.write` is doing? it's writing to the standard input of the process. If the program doesn't do anything with that (which you've given no indication that it does, simply, it seems to accept command line arguments) then there is no reason to expect that writing to standard input will be useful

Comment: @slaw "In order to work with stdin, the Java application has to be implemented to read from its standard input and perform the desired actions when input is received." If this means that it has to be able to accept whichever (String) arguments into its main -- then yes, it is implemented as such.

Comment: @rdv no that is not what that means. Maybe an example would help. Here are two different python programs; `import sys; print(sys.argv[1])`. This program accepts command line arguments. Here is another: `print(input())` this one does *not* accept command line arguments, instead, it expects a single line from standard input. You can't use standard input to work with the first, for precisely the same reason you can't use command line arguments to work with the second: because they aren't designed that way

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That example makes a lot of sense, thanks. (But -- it's not the python code that troubles me.) It seems that I have been misunderstanding a few things. I'd like to know how to achieve this call to java in the most efficient way. But perhaps the way I am doing it in the top example (but using `subprocess.run` and `shell=False`) is simply the most efficient way? Perhaps the loop is simply unavoidable?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with your loop. there is no way around some sort of loop if you want to do things multiple times. creating a process is relatively cheap, especially with no shell, although, starting up the Java runtime is a bit heavy. Maybe there is some Java specific way to approach that better, but basically that's what you have to work with

Comment: As mentioned, the loop is pretty much unavoidable. My comment was geared towards your attempt with `stdin`, which implied to me your goal is to launch the process _once_ and then reuse it, rather than launch a new process for every pair of arguments. But in order to do that, the Java application has to be implemented to read from [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#in). If it's not implemented as such, then you can't use `stdin` with the subprocess.

Comment: @slaw My initial thoughts were indeed that it is probably more efficient/computationally cheaper to launch the process once and reuse it. (Is that true?) Then it might be worthwhile to see if I can get the java code to read from stdin, if that's the only thing I need to change. I just couldn't figure out how to do that practically, i.e., what would be the initial `cmd`, and what the input to `stdin.write`. On the other hand: if it works like this, I might just leave it. Efficiency is not my biggest concern.

Comment: @rdv what everyone is getting at is that the answer is in the Java code that you haven’t provided in the question. It has to be written in such a way that you can launch it once and have it read arguments from standard input. Nobody can tell you whether that’s the case unless you include the Java code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you can make your Python code more "efficient" depends on how the Java application is implemented. If the Java application can only receive input via command line arguments, then there's nothing you can do. You'll have to launch a new subprocess for every pair of arguments. But if your Java application is implemented to read from its standard input, then you can write to `stdin` from the Python side. What that would look like depends on the protocol decided by the Java application.

You also ask what the Java command would look like if you can write to standard input. The command to launch the Java application is the same. What may be different is what command line arguments, if any, you need to pass to the Java application. And that again depends on how the Java application is implemented.

Note it *would* be cheaper to reuse the same subprocess rather than launching a new one for each pair of arguments. Especially with Java's relatively high boot time. But whether or not you *can* do this depends on the Java application.

If you control the Java application, you can modify it to read its standard input. Though you may also want to consider simply having the Java application accept more than two command line arguments (e.g., if the number of command line arguments is 40, then process them as if it was given 20 pairs).

---

Here's an example Java application that can switch between "processing" two command line arguments and "processing" an unknown number of argument pairs from standard input.

```java
package sample;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 1 && args[0].equals("--use-stdin")) {
            processArgsFromStandardInput();
        } else if (args.length == 2) {
            processArgs(args[0], args[1]);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Illegal command line. Must be --use-stdin or 2 arguments.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    static void processArgsFromStandardInput() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String arg1 = scanner.next();
            String arg2 = scanner.next();
            processArgs(arg1, arg2);
        }
    }
    
    static void processArgs(String arg1, String arg2) {
        System.out.printf("Processing args: %s, %s%n", arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

I chose to use a `Scanner`, but you can use whatever you want (e.g., `BufferedReader`, `DataInputStream`, etc.). The important part is that the source of data is `System.in` (standard input). I also chose to use `","` as the delimiter between arguments. Again, that was an arbitrary choice, and you can use whatever you want. Though it means the arguments can't contain commas themselves (I don't provide a way to "escape" a comma). Note using UTF-8 encoding and commas as the delimiter is the "protocol" I mentioned earlier.

And here's an example Python script that invokes the Java application (compiled and packaged into a JAR file) twice, once for each "mode":

```py
import subprocess
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import time


def measure_time(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        start = time()
        func(*args)
        end = time()
        print(f'Function took {end - start:.2f} seconds.')
    return wrapper


# implementation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389547/6395627
def pairwise(iterable):
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)


@measure_time
def invoke_args(jarfile, args):
    for arg1, arg2 in pairwise(args):
        subprocess.run(['java', '-jar', jarfile, arg1, arg2])


@measure_time
def invoke_stdin(jarfile, args):
    with Popen(['java', '-jar', jarfile, '--use-stdin'], stdin=PIPE) as proc:
        for arg1, arg2 in pairwise(args):
            proc.stdin.write(f'{arg1},{arg2},'.encode())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jarfile = sys.argv[1]
    args = [f'arg{i}' for i in range(1, 41)]

    print('========== COMMAND LINE ARGS ==========')
    invoke_args(jarfile, args)
    print()

    print('========= STANDARD INPUT ==========')
    invoke_stdin(jarfile, args)
    print()
```

If you invoke the above Python script (passing an appropriate JAR file path and assuming you have Java on your path), then you should see output similar to:

```
========== COMMAND LINE ARGS ==========
Processing args: arg1, arg2
Processing args: arg3, arg4
Processing args: arg5, arg6
Processing args: arg7, arg8
Processing args: arg9, arg10
Processing args: arg11, arg12
Processing args: arg13, arg14
Processing args: arg15, arg16
Processing args: arg17, arg18
Processing args: arg19, arg20
Processing args: arg21, arg22
Processing args: arg23, arg24
Processing args: arg25, arg26
Processing args: arg27, arg28
Processing args: arg29, arg30
Processing args: arg31, arg32
Processing args: arg33, arg34
Processing args: arg35, arg36
Processing args: arg37, arg38
Processing args: arg39, arg40      
Function took 2.46 seconds.        

========= STANDARD INPUT ==========
Processing args: arg1, arg2  
Processing args: arg3, arg4  
Processing args: arg5, arg6  
Processing args: arg7, arg8  
Processing args: arg9, arg10 
Processing args: arg11, arg12
Processing args: arg13, arg14
Processing args: arg15, arg16
Processing args: arg17, arg18
Processing args: arg19, arg20
Processing args: arg21, arg22
Processing args: arg23, arg24
Processing args: arg25, arg26
Processing args: arg27, arg28
Processing args: arg29, arg30
Processing args: arg31, arg32
Processing args: arg33, arg34
Processing args: arg35, arg36
Processing args: arg37, arg38
Processing args: arg39, arg40
Function took 0.16 seconds.
```

Comment: Wonderful, this is an enormous help. Accepted as the answer.