# stdout printed in stderr file while using logger

Tags: python, logging, stdout, stderr

Im using logger to print out stdout and stderr to log files. I've done this:

```
def log(process):

    logger = logging.getLogger('logging_errors')
    if not len(logger.handlers):
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(message)s')

        handler_stderr = logging.FileHandler('stderr.log')
        handler_stderr.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        handler_stderr.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler_stderr)

        handler_stdout = logging.FileHandler('stdout.log')
        handler_stdout.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler_stdout.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler_stdout)
    return logger.error(process.stderr.read())
    return logger.info(process.stdout.read())
```

A process is passed onto this function which can be something like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['FastTree -nt test.fasta'], stdin = None, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
proc.wait()
log(proc)
```

The problem I have is that the stdout is not getting printed to the stdout.log file, I get the stderr in stdout.log file.  stderr.log file is correct.  Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
return logger.error(process.stderr.read())
return logger.info(process.stdout.read())
```

The second `return` statement doesn't get executed, so the process' `stdout` is never logged. Just remove `return` from those statements, and you should find that output appears in `stdout.log`.

You're getting `stderr` output in `stdout.log` because the all logged events are passed to both handlers.

Comment: I did that and I did get the correct stdout but it only runs for one process.  I added an additional process but it ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup two loggers, one for stdout and one for stderr, but then you would have to write

```
info_logger.info(out)
error_logger.error(err)
```

And that is repetitious since you would have to choose both the appropriate logger and the appropriate level when they both contain essentially the same information.

So, we could get a little fancier and use [robert's LevelFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7447596/190597) to create one logger with two filtered handlers. The handlers each have a filter to accept only those LogRecords whose level is less than or equal to `end_level`:

```
handler.addFilter(LevelFilter(end_level))
```

Meanwhile, the statement

```
handler.setLevel(begin_level)
```

causes `handler` to accept only those LogRecords whose level is greater than `begin_level`. Combined, we have a handler that accepts only those LogRecords whose level is between `begin_level` and `end_level`. Thus, you could have one handler handle DEBUG and INFO  LogRecords, and a second handler for WARNING, ERROR and CRITICAL LogRecords.

Putting it all together, you could use something like this:

```
import logging
import subprocess

class LevelFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/7447596/190597 (robert)
    """
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level = level

    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno <= self.level

def splitlevel_logger(name, outpath='stderr.log', errpath='stdout.log',
                      fmt='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(message)s'):
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    for filename, begin_level, end_level in (
            (outpath, logging.WARNING, logging.CRITICAL),
            (errpath, logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO)):
        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename, 'w')
        handler.setLevel(begin_level)
        handler.addFilter(LevelFilter(end_level))
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

def log(out='', err=''):
    if out:
        logger.info(out)
    if err:
        logger.error(err)

logger = splitlevel_logger(__name__)
cmd = 'FastTree -nt test.fasta'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
log(*proc.communicate())
```

---

By the way, note the warning concerning [subprocess.Popen.wait](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

> Warning
>
> [Popen.wait] will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the
>   child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks
>   waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate()
>   to avoid that.

So it is potentially buggy to use `Popen.wait` in the situation you have above. Use `Popen.communicate` to avoid this problem.
Or, if you want to read and log output as it comes out of the subprocess (instead of recieving it only after the subprocess completes) [use threading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/190597) or [select.select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4838875/190597).